# why LSTM model output same hidden state at last layer

Tags: pytorch, lstm

In my simple LSTM model, the last hidden state are almost same cross all batch data.

the model

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

lstm = nn.LSTM(
    input_size=5,
    hidden_size=6,
    num_layers=5,
    batch_first=True
)

i = torch.rand(9,8,5)

out1, (h_n, h_c) = lstm(i)

print('out.size()', out1.size())
print('h_n.size()', h_n.size())
print('h_c.size()', h_c.size())

print(h_n[-1])
```

the out put

```
out.size() torch.Size([9, 8, 6])
h_n.size() torch.Size([5, 9, 6])
h_c.size() torch.Size([5, 9, 6])
tensor([[ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1907, -0.0785,  0.0751],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1906, -0.0785,  0.0750],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1907, -0.0785,  0.0751],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1906, -0.0785,  0.0750],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1907, -0.0785,  0.0751],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1906, -0.0785,  0.0751],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1906, -0.0786,  0.0750],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1906, -0.0785,  0.0750],
        [ 0.1515,  0.2575,  0.0636, -0.1907, -0.0786,  0.0751]],
```

The out put are almost same. If decrease the layer number, it will be better.

Comment: Have you tried training the model for some epochs, and then checking again the outputs? Also, if possible, I would increase `hidden_size`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.